# Trying to Animate a ImageView, does not work

Tags: android, animation

Animation file to get the zoom in the view from top left to full screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<scale
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXScale=".1"
    android:fromYScale=".1"
    android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"/>
</set>
```

In the onCreate I have

```
newHintAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.newhintzoomin);
newHintAnimation.setAnimationListener(this) ;
```

In my onClick

```
try {
    hintBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getApplicationContext()                    .getAssets().open("logos/"+question.getShintFileName()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    hintBitmap = null ;
    e.printStackTrace();

hintImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
hintImage.setImageBitmap(hintBitmap);
newHintAnimation.reset() ;
hintImage.startAnimation(newHintAnimation) ;
```

My layout xml has the following

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hintImage"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question_header_layout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

I checked, I am not get a null on the bitmap. If run the same code in a Activity using overridePendingTransition(R.anim.newhintzoomin, 0) ; it works.

Comment: What's the exact error ? The animation just doesn't start ?

Comment: I assume that you only forgot to put } on catch statement while you're asking this question, not in real? Otherwise, that can be the case... Because you set hintImage to null or not doing anything.

Comment: The animation does not start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this is :

```
Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.newhintzoomin);
hintImage.startAnimation(newHintAnimation);
```

Let me know if it works :) Good Luck

Comment: More than anything else, its important to know how to debug :), thanks.